# Take a picture when a light source is disturbed

Tags: python, serial, picamera

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi camera to take a picture when a light source sent to the camera is interrupted. I have one Arduino (transmitter) sending an ON-OFF Keying (OOK) signal through an LED to a second Arduino (receiver) with a phototransistor. Then when the light communication between the two is disturbed, the receiver should send a "Take a picture" command to the Raspberry Pi through a USB serial connection. When the Raspberry Pi receives the "Take a picture" command from the connected Arduino it should take a picture.

I have managed to do the visible light communication between the two Arduinos using IDE. I have also managed to get the Arduino on the receiver side to communicate with the Raspberry Pi when the light communication is disturbed (sending the "Take a picture" command). I have also managed to get the camera to take a picture. However, I am struggling to combine my two codes in Python. This is how I combined my codes:

```
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import picamera 

ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)  #change ACM number as found from ls /dev/tty/ACM*
ser.baudrate=9600

def Blink(pin):   
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)  
    time.sleep(1)  
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)  
    time.sleep(1)  
    return

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

while True:    
    read_ser=ser.readline()
    print(read_ser)
    if(read_ser=="Take a picture"):
        #import picamera
        print("About to take a picture")
        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                camera.resolution=(1280,720)
                camera.capture("/home/pi/Desktop/newimage.jpg")
                print("picture taked")
```

The camera does not take a picture when the light communication is disturbed,  I believe the problem lies on the line `if(read_ser=="Take a picture"):` and onwards because the code does not work from there.

Can you please help me?

Comment: all you need to do is take a photo when the lightsource gpio pin value goes low, so change `if lumi > threshold:` to `if lumi < threshold:`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code from there will work, all you need to do is change the condition:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc as spmisc

img = spmisc.imread(filename, flatten=True)
lumi = np.sum(img)
if lumi < threshold:
    # do something
```

Notice the change from:

```
if lumi > threshold:
```

to:

```
if lumi < threshold:
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Motion?  Latest version is on GitHub.
An interruption in the light will be more than enough to suggest movement and trigger a photo.